# how to do a loop in chunks in python

Tags: python

I have a file with 100 lines. I am reading it into python

`Input = [line.rstrip() for line in open("input.txt")]`

Input has 100 lines, but I have a function that can only handle 20 at at time.

How do I do something like:

`for (20 lines) in Input as lines:
    magic_function(lines)`

I think the term I am looking for is either chunking or iterating? But I feel like I am not searching right because the info I m finding seems more complex than it should be.

Answer (score 2):

Try slicing your main list to sub-lists of 20 and then process it.

**Ex:**

```
Input = [line.rstrip() for line in open("input.txt")]
InPut = [Input[line:line+20] for line in range(0, len(Input), 20)]
for chunk in Input:
    for line in chunk:
        #process
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is really big then running `Input = [line.rstrip() for line in open("input.txt")]` will use a lot of memory. It's better to stream it while reading 20 lines at a time:

```
lines = []
for idx, l in enumerate(open("input.txt")):
    lines.append(l.rstrip())
    if (idx + 1) % 20 == 0:
        for line in lines:
            # process
        lines = []  # reset
# process any last remaining lines that wasn't caught in the modulo if
for line in lines:
    # process
```